# MPMediaQuery songsQuery always return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-player

Sample code is expected to play a song available from the iPhone library:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *myPlayer =
[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
[myPlayer setQueueWithQuery: [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]];
[myPlayer play];
```

However an exception is thrown on SongsQuery as it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from IOS 10.0, the `plist` needs to be updated. In short , create a new row `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` in the `plist` and mentioned the reason why you want to access the media library. Build, it works!